# Share directory over internet with Windows 10 computers

Tags: internet, samba, directory, file-sharing

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop and would like to share several directories over the internet with remote Windows 10 computers.
It's possible??
Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

[samba](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man7/samba.7.html) is the package which enables this. See https://www.samba.org/ then read the documentation at https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/ .

Please note that there are significant security implications to running this server, and the [smb.conf(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/smb.conf.5.html) manual page should be regarded as mandatory reading before proceeding with installation.

You will also need to determine if you must have a static IP address to enable access from outside your local network, or how to connect without one if not. Since your questions should be reasonably scoped, that question is [outside the scope of this question](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask), and must be resolved separately.

Determine if you need your Ubuntu machine which will be the samba server to also be a Domain Controller, then install with

*Not a Domain Controller*

```
sudo apt-get install acl attr samba samba-dsdb-modules samba-vfs-modules winbind krb5-config krb5-user
```

*Also a Domain Controller*

```
sudo apt-get install acl attr samba samba-dsdb-modules samba-vfs-modules winbind libpam-winbind libnss-winbind libpam-krb5 krb5-config krb5-user dnsutils
```